# Renaming the group in Active directory to an other existing group name will have any effect on the existing group?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I have 2 groups in active directory A & B, these groups has its own members. If at some case, I wanted to rename A group to B group (through code), Will the existing A group members will be reflected as B group members after renaming and will there be any change to the B group members??

Comment: Dont you have a test environment to try it by yourself?

Comment: No, currently we don't have an testing environment as this requires a separate domain.